# Shared Instance property in protocol

Tags: ios, swift

I have to keep shared instance property in the protocol. While passing protocol type in class init I am getting error 'Protocol 'EnvironmentProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements'.

```
protocol EnvironmentProtocol {
   static var shared: Self { get set }
}
final class Enviorenment: EnvironmentProtocol {
  static var shared: Enviorenment = Enviorenment()

  private init() { }
}
class Home {
  let env: EnvironmentProtocol

  init(env: EnvironmentProtocol) {
    self.env = env
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove this error you can refactor the `Home` class like this:

```
class Home<T:EnvironmentProtocol> {
  let env: T

  init(env: T) {
    self.env = env
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But still, I am not able to understand the reason why it didn't work in the first place.

Comment: 'Self' in the 'EnvironmentProtocol' is not a type. It's just a template that you should fill later. When a compiler works with the class 'Home' it doesn't know about class 'Enviorenment'. But it sees that you must give him a concret class to substitute 'Self'. So you can give him this class explicitly (e.g. 'Enviorenment') or use generics again by adding '<T:EnvironmentProtocol>'.

Answer (score 0):

As Emin mentioned this is the best way to resolve the error,

```
class Home<T: EnvironmentProtocol> {
   typealias EnvironmentType = T
   let env: EnvironmentType

   init(env: EnvironmentType) {
     self.env = env
   }
 }
```

You can use only a single type that conforms to EnvironmentProtocol

```
let home: Home<MyMemberClass> = Home()
```